# Redirect Nginx to a Wordpress running behind apache2 server

Tags: nginx, wordpress, apache2, proxypass

I have a unique problem that I don't how to put in and I can't change the situation (orders from above!). Please read it all before down-voting me.

In this scenario, I have two servers, Server A and Server B. Server A is using Nginx to deliver APIs. Server B is using apache to host blogs. Previously, Server B was serving the blog using the `blogs.abc.com` domain, while server A was using `abc.com`. Everything is all good, fair and square.

Now, the requirements came that I have to host the blog in the `ABC.com\blogs` portion of the URL, instead of `blogs.abc.com`. In Nginx, I can use proxy_pass to direct resource to another server/domain name, I have done it before. I could direct the URL `abc.com\blogs` to `bogs.abc.com`, no sweat. It would have worked. But the blog is running in WordPress and I have to put my base URL on the WordPress settings. If I put `blogs.abc.com` in the settings, whenever I go to the URL, `abc.com\blogs`, the URL would automatically be changed. I have tested it, WordPress does it. And if I change the settings URL to `abc.com\blogs` for WordPress's base URL, even though server B's namespace is in `blogs.abc.com`, the blog break-down. WordPress can't find the static files anymore. (Tested that as well!).

My BIG QUESTION

Is there anyway that I don't know of, I can redirect the server A using proxy_pass to Server B, without the URL being changed? (All the URL's has o be in `abc.com\blogs\......`)

Why I am not using Server A to host the blog?

Because Server A is using nginx, and all the APIs and database are in there. For security reasons and (other purposes that I don't know), it was decided that blogs should be in a separate server. Besides, running WordPress on an nginx server (with both MySQL and PostgreSQL) running side-by-side will be a gigantic hassle!

It's going to be bad for SEO

Yes! I was told to do it.

Comment: URLs always use the forward slash, could it be the problem?

Comment: Please show output of `nginx -T` with the configuration where WordPress cannot find static files. Also please clarify, what does "WordPress cannot find static files" mean exactly? It would be also useful to see exact HTTP requests that fail with the config you tried.